# Replace all values in Dataframe with their count per column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = ([1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

   0  1
0  1  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  1  2
4  3  4
5  3  2
```

The desired output would be a count of all occurrences for each value in df. Desired output below:

```
   0  1
0  2  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  2  1
5  2  2
```

There are 2 "1"'s in the first column, 1 "2", 1 "4", 2 "3"'s. ETC for each column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map each column (Series `s`) to its value count:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s.map(s.value_counts()))                                                                                        
   0  1
0  2  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  2  1
5  2  2
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is using transform on each columns:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x).transform('count'))
```

Or using Counter with replace:

```
from collections import Counter
df.replace(df.apply(Counter))
```

---

```
   0  1
0  2  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  2  1
5  2  2
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can leverage [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np

def count_values(s):
    _, idx, cnt = np.unique(s, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    return cnt[idx]

df.apply(count_values)
   0  1
0  2  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  2  1
5  2  2
```